# OSError: [Errno 13] when running CGIHTTPServer

Tags: python, ubuntu, cgi

*I am on A Ubuntu Server and when I run  `python -m CGIHTTPServer 80`

it works fine. But then I go to the website it shows this:*

```
172.16.1.19 - - [25/Feb/2017 17:23:52] "GET /cgi-bin/weather.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 248, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

*I use an iframe to connect to the CGI script*

Answer (score 0):

`/cgi-bin/weather.py` should be executable.

Make sure you gave the file proper permission. For example:

```
chmod u+x /cgi-bin/weather.py
```

Comment: I have multiple files there so should give permission to the directory?

Comment: @HaaruunI, You need to set execution permissions to all of the cgi scripts. The directory that contains the scripts should be also accessbiel (`x` permission)